# static classes and multiple instances on azure

Tags: c#, azure

I'm building an app that will be deployed on Azure.

If I use a static class, will all the instances have access to the same exact static object or will each instance have its own static object instantiated when each instance is spawn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each instance will have it's own static data, as they are completely separate from each other and run in isolation.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If I want to create a static object that's shared by all instances, what should I use?

Comment: @frenchie You need to come up with some other mechanism to "share" that data.  There is no equivalent to a single "static object" in cloud development.  In general, this usually means saving the data in a database, and loading/saving it as needed.

Comment: you could also look at using Azure cache or table storage instead of databases

Answer (score 7):

`static` fields have one value per AppDomain.

They emphatically do not share values across computers.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If I want to create a static object that's shared by all instances, what should I use?

Comment: @frenchie: Use a database.

Answer (score 2):

If your objective is to share variables among instances, I would recommend taking a look at Windows Azure Caching where you either use a part of your role instance or a separate role for caching purposes. Objects in this cache can then be used by all instances of your role. For more details, please look at this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/06/18/difference-between-windows-azure-cache-preview-and-windows-azure-share-cache.aspx.

Hope this helps.