# Azure: Share object instance between webrole and web service

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-web-roles

I have an Azure Webrole which has an MVC application and a WCF service. 
In the "OnStart" method of the webrole, I instantiate a static variable that representes an IOC Container.

After that, when I make an external service call and I try to get the container, the variable is null...

Am I missing something or why isn't the static available to the service?

If it matters I'm running Azure SDK 1.8

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810590/static-classes-and-multiple-instances-on-azure

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you mean. You initialize your IOC container in the WebRole.cs class and after that you try to use it in a WCF Service or in your MVC application which is hosted in the **same** Web Role **instance**.

Well, that's not possible. You have to know that the code running in WebRole.cs runs in a different process (WaIISHost.exe) than your actual Web Application (MVC website/WCF service in w3wp.exe):

[image]

This is explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/12/02/new-full-iis-capabilities-differences-from-hosted-web-core.aspx) in detail.

If you want to initialize your IOC container for your Web Application you should do this in the Global.asax file. And if you also want to use the IOC container in the WebRole.cs (to do some work before the Web Application starts), you will also need to initialize it in the WebRole.cs file (since these are 2 different processes).

Answer (score 0):

If your WebRole has two sites/roles, one for the MVC App and one for the WCF Service (check your configuration), then you are running two independent applications in the same WebRole (Cloud Service VM), each with different endpoints.  You can't share static resources across applications.  You'll need to instantiate an instance in your WCF service as well.